# Android Studio-Java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio, and i'm facing a problem which is how to set the content view before getting to sign up and sign in forms
In this application the first page on the emulator that shows up is the Register.
I have Created Sign-up, Sign-In, MainActivity, and Base Activity and I want to set base activity as the first page the pops up in the emulator

My code is :

```
Base Activity:
public class Base_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button mButton,mButton2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);


        mButton=findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton2=findViewById(R.id.button2);



        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));

            }
        });
        mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class));

            }
        });
    }
}

Register:
 private static final String TAG = "Register";
    EditText mFullame, mEmail, mPassword, mPhone;
    Button mRegisterBtn;
    TextView mLoginBtn;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String userID;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mFullame = findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPhone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);


        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();//we are getting the instance
        // of the database from the firebase
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
Login:

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    Button mLoginBtn;
    TextView mCreateBtn, forgotTextLink;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mCreateBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        forgotTextLink = findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);


        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();//trim=format
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is Required");
                    return;

                }//and so on...
Main Activity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    TextView fullName, email, phone, verifyMsg;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userId;
    Button resendCode;
    Button resetPassLocal;
    FirebaseUser user;
    Button logout;
    ImageView profileImage;
    Button changeProfileImage;
    StorageReference storageReference;//for storing image on firebase


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);

        resetPassLocal = findViewById(R.id.resetPasswordLocal);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        resendCode = findViewById(R.id.resendCode);
        verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and change the name to the activity you want to start at the beginning.

```
<activity android:name=".Base_Activity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```